# MySQL - SQLite How to improve this very simple query?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have one simple but large table.

```
id_tick   INTEGER      eg: 1622911
price     DOUBLE       eg: 1.31723
timestamp DATETIME     eg: '2010-04-28 09:34:23'
```

For 1 month of data, I have 2.3 millions rows (150MB)

My query aims at returning the latest price at a given time.

I first set up a SQLite table and used the query:

```
SELECT max(id_tick), price, timestamp 
FROM EURUSD 
WHERE timestamp <='2010-04-16 15:22:05'
```

It is running in 1.6s.

As I need to run this query several thousands of time, 1.6s is by far too long...

I then set up a MySQL table and modified the query (the max function differs from MySQL to SQLite):

```
SELECT id_tick, price, timestamp
FROM EURUSD
WHERE id_tick = (SELECT MAX(id_tick) 
                 FROM EURUSD WHERE timestamp <='2010-04-16 15:22:05')
```

Execution time is getting far worse 3.6s
(I know I can avoid the sub query using ORDER BY and LIMIT 1 but it does not improve the execution time.)

I am only using one month of data for now, but I will have to use several years at some point.

My questions are then the following:

1. is there a way to improve my query?
2. given the large dataset, should I use another database engine?
3. any tips ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure you have an index on timestamp

2) Assuming that id_tick is both the PRIMARY KEY and Clustered Index, and assuming that id_tick increments as a function of time (since you are doing a MAX)

You can try this:

```
SELECT id_tick, price, timestamp 
FROM EURUSD 
WHERE id_tick = (SELECT id_tick
                   FROM EURUSD WHERE timestamp <='2010-04-16 15:22:05'
                   ORDER BY id_tick DESC
                   LIMIT 1)
```

This should be similar to janmoesen's performance though, since there should be high page correlation between id_tick and timestamp in any event

Comment: Also, using partitioning will help protect performance as more data is added.

Comment: 1) I have an index on timestamp and id_tick
2) all assumptions are correct

You query is executed in 6.2s

Comment: Try dropping and recreating the indexes - something has gone horribly wrong with statistics or cached plans IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any indexed fields ?

indexing `timestamp` and/or `id_tick` could change a lot of things.

Also why don't you use an interval for timestamp ?

```
WHERE timestamp >= '2010-04-15 15:22:05' AND timestamp <= '2010-04-16 15:22:05'
```

that would ease the burden of the MAX function.

Comment: yes, timestamp and id_tick are already indexed.

Adding an interval does not make a difference here, even if it is a very small interval.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing analysis using ALL the ticks for large intervals? I'd tried to filter data into minute/hour/day etc. graphs.

Comment: No I am only using a very limited number of ticks, what about breaking down the data in may tables? 
Instead of EURUSD, I would have EURUSD_20100501, EURUSD_20100502 ... one table a day ?

Comment: Split would help, I guess, but you will have to deal with borders.

Comment: no, no, no, no ! you need to treat this as a snowflake schema with a number of dimension tables such as time, currency etc and a forex fact table.

Comment: to deal with borders, I was thinking of always using the union of two tables (I will not need more)

@foo I am not familiar with snowflake schema (and google is not helping), would you mind elaborate a bit or posting a link to explicit your point ? thks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I guess my index was corrupted somehow, a re-indexation greatly improved the performance.

The following is now executed in 0.0012s (non cached)

```
SELECT id_tick, price, timestamp
FROM EURUSD
WHERE timestamp <= '2010-05-11 05:30:10'
ORDER by id_tick desc
LIMIT 1
```

Thanks!