# How to improve SQLite query in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm sort of lost on this. I have an application that is reading from a static SQLite database that has 439397 records (~32MB).

I am querying the database on a column that is indexed, but the it takes ~8-12 seconds to finish the query. The current query I am using is to do database.query(tableName, columnHeaders, "some_id=" + id) for a list of ids.

I tried doing the "WHERE some_id IN (id1, id2, id3)" approach, but that took over twice as long. I have a feeling that I might be doing it wrong.

The query is done in an AsyncTask, so I am at a lost at what other thing I could do to improve the performance.

- UPDATE:

I resolved the problem by changing the behavior of the application.

Comment: did you consider using "limit"

Comment: I need all of the records that match :(

Comment: How many ids are there in your list.

Comment: Anything on these lines? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626419/mysql-sqlite-how-to-improve-this-very-simple-query?rq=1

Comment: approximately 200-300 ids in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) to confirm that your index is indeed being properly used.

You can try running your query once with a `COUNT(*)` instead of the real column list, to see if the issue is the act of actually reading the row data off of flash storage (which is possible if there are lots of matches and lots of big columns).

You can try running your query to match on a single ID (rather than N of them), to start to try to get a handle on whether the issue is too many comparisons.

However, please bear in mind that `AsyncTask` does not somehow make things magically faster. It makes things magically not run on the main application thread.

Comment: I can confirm that the index is being used. Also, without the index, the query would take up over a minute. Should I do the query on a thread then?

Comment: @ktklam9: You already are doing the query on a thread -- the thread supplied by the `AsyncTask`. Again, simply moving the query to the background will not make the query take less time, but it will stop you from getting an ANR by tying up the main application thread.

Comment: What about splitting the query to several threads? Some devices are multicore, results might be wrapped with MergeCursor.

Comment: @pawelzieba: That is unlikely to help overall speed, if the flash storage is the gating factor. However, doing a few smaller queries, serialized, might be useful if the UI could render partial results (e.g., from the first few IDs) to give the user something to chew on while the rest of the work is being done.

Comment: The problem  is that I need all of the records before I can display something to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have an index on that field. Note that the index might need to cover several fields if you use them for filtering/sorting/grouping in your real query (can't tell in more details because I haven't seen it).